# Connect two HashMap Values

Tags: java, json, hashmap, gson

I've got this JSON string:

`String json = "{\"countries\":{\"2\":\"China\",\"3\":\"Russia \",\"4\":\"USA\"},\"capitals\":{\"2\":Beijing,\"4\":null,\"3\":Moscow}}";`
I converted string to HashMap, using this:

```
   HashMap<String,Object> map = new Gson().fromJson(json, new TypeToken<HashMap<String, Object>>(){}.getType());
   System.out.println(map.get("countries")+"@@@@@"+map.get("capitals"));
```

And now my output is:

```
{2=China, 3=Russia , 4=USA}@@@@@{2=Beijing, 4=null, 3=Moscow}
```

I would like to connect this values by numbers. I want to create two ArrayList like this:

A)- [China,Russia,USA]

B)- [Beijing,Moscow,null]

How can i do it?

Comment: What have you tried? Have you tried Array.from-ing the results?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you need to cast `map.get("label")` to `LinkedTreeMap<Integer, String>`, then create new ArrayList with it's values

```
        String json = "{\"countries\":{\"2\":\"China\",\"3\":\"Russia \",\"4\":\"USA\"},\"capitals\":{\"2\":Beijing,\"4\":null,\"3\":Moscow}}";
        HashMap<String,TreeMap<Integer, String>> map = new Gson().fromJson(json, new TypeToken<HashMap<String, TreeMap<Integer, String>>>(){}.getType());
        ArrayList<String> countries = new ArrayList<>(map.get("countries").values());
        System.out.println(countries);

        ArrayList<String> capitals = new ArrayList<>(map.get("capitals").values());
        System.out.println(capitals);
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but the output is : [China, Russia , USA] [Beijing, null, Moscow]. I would like to achieve: [China, Russia , USA] [Beijing, Moscow, null].

Comment: @MordorT.T Ok, I added Collections.sort(), you can try it again

Comment: I've got: Attempt to invoke interface method 'int java.lang.Comparable.compareTo(java.lang.Object)' on a null object reference

Comment: @MordorT.T I double-check this time, try it again

Comment: I've got error surrounded error (I can't use this sort function in my project)

Comment: @MordorT.T humh, that means your java is not compatible. I'll update my solution for lower's versions

Comment: Actually, this solution is not efficient enough. You can avoid sorting the lists.

Comment: @Leuteris with the output of this question, you have to

Comment: Why not use `Map<String, TreeMap<Integer, String>>` and the corresponding type token? The outer map would be an interface since you don't really care the order (therefore no need to use the Gson internal map implementation), whilst the inner map based on the `TreeMap` implementation whose entries are sorted by keys (that Gson can convert to integers automatically) can do the trick? The both `map.get("countries").values()` and `map.get("capitals").values()` would produce ordered results. Additionally, making it all inner-joined by keys, not by position, would be the best (and correct). though.

Comment: @fluffy I see, I didn't know `TreeMap` maintains ascending order. Thanks for pointing out, also can you double-check my code?

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate over the country keyset to fill the capital array:

```
List<String> countries = new ArrayList<>(countriesMap.values());
List<String> capitals = new ArrayList<>();

for (String countryKey : countriesMap.keySet()) {
    capitals.add(capitalsMap.get(countryKey));
}
```